# How to set activex name?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, user-controls

hello my friends i creat an activex with vb.net for ms-access
i use that code to regestir that

```
<ProgId("AFor Test Listview BySedo")> 
<ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)>
 Public Class UserControl1
 Public Const EventsId As String = "50965EF1-E501-42E9-8E8A-BCDBFA44DE1E"
 Public Sub New()
 InitializeComponent() 
End Sub
```

and that code

```
 <ComRegisterFunction()>
    Public Shared Sub RegisterClass(ByVal key As String)
        Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder(key)
        sb.Replace("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\", "")
        Dim k As RegistryKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(sb.ToString(), True)
        Dim ctrl As RegistryKey = k.CreateSubKey("Control")
        ctrl.Close()
        Dim inprocServer32 As RegistryKey = k.OpenSubKey("InprocServer32", True)
        inprocServer32.SetValue("CodeBase", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)
        inprocServer32.Close()
        k.Close()
    End Sub
```

but name in activex show like that  AFor_Test_Listview_BySedo.UserControl1

how can i set that name ?

Comment: You have the line `<ProgId("AFor Test Listview BySedo")>` in your code, have you tried to change it?

Comment: How?  You mean chose another name or change all line

Comment: Choose another name that would answer your question. The name in ActiveX is a combination of the `ProgId` and the Class name

Comment: i know that i want to know  why he give me the (_) between the words

Comment: when i change progid string name my active x didnt apper with new name still with old name